# PHP exception cant be raised properly

Tags: php

I am new to PHP exceptions. When I tried the code something like

```
<?php

if ($number != 0) {
    throw new Exception('number not equal to 0');
}
return true;

try {
$number = 0;
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";

}
```

I get a blank screen and no exception is raised.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here???

Comment: what i need is to raise an exception ..here i get a blank screen..i need to throw an exception when $number != 0

Comment: See an example here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 2):

Just like any (widely-used) programming language, PHP reads your code from the top to the bottom (there are some exceptions, but for the purposes of this question it is useless to explain them).

Thus, when your script begins, it compares `$number` to `0`. Since you haven't set it yet, it evaluates to be equivalent to `0` and will NOT throw the exception. It then runs `return true;` which [when called in the global scope, ends the execution of the current script](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php), and does not pass onto any more code.

Even without the `return` statement, if the script had continued onto the next block, there would be no exception raised because your statements literally mean to `try` setting `$number` to `0`, which should not fail.

You have several options, including encapsulating your code in a `function` block, or employing a solution similar to the one `@donald123` gave in his example (throwing the exception within the `try` block).

Answer (score 0):

Please read the manual at www.php.net:

```
 <?php 
    $number = 0; // Set the Value
    try {
         if($number != 0) throw new Exception('number not equal to 0',E_ERROR);
         echo "Number gt 0";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
         echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";

    }
    // CONTINUE
  ?>
```